# `echo -e 'Q\ns\nV' | sort` doesn't sort

Tags: sort, case-sensitivity

Why do :

```
$ echo -e 'Q\ns\nV'  | sort
```

outputs

```
Q
s
V
```

without changing the order of my list (taking in account the lower/uppercase ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most languages, `s` sorts before `V` regardless of the case.

Sorting depends on localisation settings (`LANG` and `LC_*` variables).

You could use: `LC_ALL=C sort` if you wanted to sort according to the byte value order, but that may not do what you want if you're in a multi-byte locale.

If you want to sort in the order of your own language, but having uppercase letters before lowercase ones, you could do:

```
sed 's/./0&/g;s/0\([[:lower:]]\)/1\1/g' |
  sort |
sed 's/.\(.\)/\1/g'
```

That would cause lower-case letters to be sorted after every other character.

```
$ print -l Q s d é f D É F V | sort
d
D
é
É
f
F
Q
s
V

$ print -l Q s d é f D É F V | sed 's/./0&/g;s/0\([[:lower:]]\)/1\1/g' |
 sort |
 sed 's/.\(.\)/\1/g'
D
É
F
Q
V
d
é
f
s
```

That would only work in locales where collating elements are single characters only.

Comment: thank you, but I'm really surprised by the sentence "In most languages, s sorts before V regardless of the case.". That sounds weird :-)

Comment: @Pierre. Does it? In the yellow pages in your country, are upper case names sorted before lower case ones?

Comment: I meant, I didn't use the -i option, so I expected the uppercase to be sorted before the lowercase ...

Comment: There are no "lower case names", "Jorge de la Puente" has "Puente" as last name.

Answer (score 3):

`sort`'s sort order depends on your environment's locale settings. From the `sort` manpage.

```
   *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort  order.
   Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.
```

The POSIX or C locale will make `sort` behave as expected:

```
reedm@www:~ $ echo -e 'Q\ns\nV' | LC_ALL='' sort 
Q
s
V
reedm@www:~ $ echo -e 'Q\ns\nV' | LC_ALL='' sort --ignore-case
Q
s
V
reedm@www:~ $ echo -e 'Q\ns\nV' | LC_ALL='c' sort 
Q
V
s
reedm@www:~ $ echo -e 'Q\ns\nV' | LC_ALL='c' sort --ignore-case
Q
s
V
```